# Storing an audio file in a UIDocument

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, icloud, uidocument

I have a little app that works with iCloud. It stores audio files into the cloud. I noticed that loading the audio files from a second device doesn't work immediately. So I implemented

```
- (BOOL)downloadFileIfNotAvailable:(NSURL*)file
```

That helped but still it works sluggish.
I wanted to speed up the downloading process on other iCloud devices by wrapping the audio file in a UIDocument. Is this even possible? I could store the file contents in a NSData, but is there a point (seeing as how AVAudioPlayer wants a URL)? Is there another way for me to speed up the synchronization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSFileCoordinator's coordinateReadingItemAtURL method for this.  Take a look at the answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675303/icloud-callback-for-nsfilemanagers-startdownloadingubiquitousitematurl)?